# 'The Windows PowerShell snap-in'Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell is not installed on this machine' on SP Server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I made a fresh SP 2013 installation on win 2008 R2 SP1. When access SP Mgmt Shell, I am getting the following error - "Add-PSSnapin : The Windows PowerShell snap-in'Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell' is not installed on this machine".

As far as SharePoint is concerned, site and central admin are working fine. How do I fix this issue ? Do I need to add thing to Path variable ?

Comment: If you run "Get-PSSnapin | select name" is the SharePoint module listed?  If it is, can you open an elevated PowerShell, and run "add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell" does it load without the error?

Comment: Hi Jesus, It is not listing SP. Just showing - Microsoft.Powershel.Core

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to run this in a powershell window to install the .dll, seems something has messed up your installation:

```
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil /LogToConsole=true C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell\v4.0_15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell.dll
```

(just copy paste the whole thing in to the window and click Enter)

[Source (comment for 2013)](http://vintentou.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/error-the-windows-powershell-snap-in-microsoft-sharepoint-powershell-is-not-install/)

Comment: (Just copy paste the whole thing and click enter) haha not usually a good idea

Comment: This doesn't work for me as that file doesn't exist in the pointed path.

Comment: I'm follow your command but doesn't work for me and here are error message Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell\v4.0_15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell.dll
' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.. Please help Jomchai