# PowerShell Cannot find Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.dll

Tags: powershell

**EDIT:** I wrote this question in a misleading way. I should clarify that while I am on SharePoint Server 2010, I have admin rights on a SharePoint site. I do not have Foundation or Server apps.

I was having a similar problem as the link below, except I am using Windows PowerShell to install the Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell.dll file. When I attempted the fix, I got this message in PowerShell:

> "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell\v4.0_15.0.0.0_71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file
>   specified."

How else can I get Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.dll?

['The Windows PowerShell snap-in'Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell is not installed on this machine' on SP Server](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/82797/the-windows-powershell-snap-inmicrosoft-sharepoint-powershell-is-not-installed/82798#82798)

Comment: Are you on a SharePoint Server? Can you explain if this is a new installation, what version, what service pack, etc.

Comment: I am on SharePoint Server 2010. This is not a new installation. I am unsure of the version. No additional service packs installed as far as I know.

Comment: And when does this error pop up? Can you explain the recreation steps? Do you have administrator rights to the server?

Comment: I have admin rights to the server. To try to install the .dll file I need, I used Windows PowerShell and type "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil /LogToConsole=true C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell\v4.0_15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell.dll", then I receive the error.

Comment: Chris Did you resolve your issue? I can't find a copy of dll either. I am still on version 2. If you had the solution, do you mind sharing?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/979/

Answer (score 1):

For sharepoint 2010, you have to run the command which compatibale for .net 3.5,try this

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\InstallUtil /LogToConsole=true C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell\14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell.dll
```

the command you mentioned is for .net 4.0 but in 2010 mostly we are on .net 3.5.

Comment: I just tried it, and I'm getting the same error I described. Except the directory path is "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell\v4.0_15.0.0.0_71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.dll". Maybe I didn't install something, so that's why I don't have the .dll?

Answer (score 1):

What are you ultimately trying to do? Load the powershell snapin? Use `Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell` in the powershell console to load it. Installing SharePoint should automatically put the dll where it needs to.

Comment: That is precisely what I am trying to do. The problem is the dll isn't on my computer. I only installed SharePoint designer and have access to a SharePoint server (not the software). It seems that I need to install the SP Server Application.

Comment: You need to be on the SharePoint server in order for this to work. Otherwise, if you want to do remote powershell sessions, you can do a command, you need to look into PSRemote: http://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/