# Sharepoint Module in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to use get-SPsite to get a list of SharePoint sites for my company, but Powershell doesn't recognize any SharePoint cmdlts. I preume because there's no SharePoint module installed? I've looked at other similar questions, and I've tried setting my execution policy to unrestricted and typing...

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell"
```

but it replies with

> "No snap-ins have been registered for Windows Powershell version 3".

I'm using SharePoint 2013, I don't know if that has anything to do with it. Can anyone help me get access to the SharePoint cmdlts?

Comment: May be this link will help you. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pasen/2011/04/06/resolving-error-no-snap-ins-have-been-registered-for-windows-powershell-version-2/

Comment: Are you running it "as administrator"? Also, are you running it at SharePoint server itself? is the account local administrator? Have you run this command twice (and at it first time "did nothing")?

Answer (score 3):

To Make sure that `Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell` Snapin is registered on your machine, you should do the following:

- Run Powershell as administrator.
- Type the below cmdlet.

  ```
  Get-PSSnapin -Registered
  ```

[image]

If the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell` Snapin is not listed in the above result, so you should register it as mentioned in this thread ['The Windows PowerShell snap-in'Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell is not installed on this machine' on SP Server](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/82797/the-windows-powershell-snap-inmicrosoft-sharepoint-powershell-is-not-installed)